# C# Invalidate automatic ToString conversion

Tags: c#, tostring, implicit-conversion

In C#, I have a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int id;
}
```

Currently, when I do:

```
Person person = new Person
{
    name = "John",
    id = 3
}
// Will be converted Console.Writeline("Person = " + person.ToString()); by the compiler
Console.Writeline("Person = " + person);
```

What can I do in the class to invalidate the automatic conversion from person to person.ToString() and make the compiler give an error to indicate Person object cannot be converted to string implicitly?

Comment: ToString() can always be called on an Object. I don't think this is possible actually

Comment: You could write a source code analyzer. Shouldn't be too hard using roslyn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What can I do in the class to invalidate the automatic conversion from
>   person to person.ToString() and make the compiler give an error to
>   indicate Person object cannot be converted to string implicitly?

You can't, at least not in an easy way. The overload of `string` + `object` will be the one emitting the `ToString` on `object`, which you have no way of controlling. This is specified in [Addition Operator (7.7.4)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375(v=vs.71).aspx) part of the specification (emphasis mine):

> The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both
>   operands are of type string. If an operand of string concatenation is
>   null, an empty string is substituted. **Otherwise, any non-string
>   argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the
>   virtual ToString method inherited from type object.** If ToString
>   returns null, an empty string is substituted.

What you can do, which isn't a compile-time warning, is throw an exception from an overloaded `ToString`. I would definitely recommend *not doing that*. You could possibly write a Roslyn analyzer which looks for any object passed to `Console.WriteLine` without overriding the `ToString` method and emit a warning for that.

Comment: Actually it's the overload of the `+` operator accepting a `string` and `object`, not the overload of `Console.WriteLine`, in the example shown.

Comment: @Servy Right. Fixed. I thought it was passing it to `Console.WriteLine(object)`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to write your programming language that doesn't have an overload of the + operator accepting a string and an object as its two operands.  As it is, if you're using C# which states that such an operator overload *is required as a part of the language specs*, the code that you've shown *must* compile in C#.  In order to make that operation not compile would require using a language that doesn't meet the C# language specs.

Answer (score -1):

Using the new keyword when overriding the ToString method and marking it as obsolete looks to do the trick.

```
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int id;

    [Obsolete("this should not be used", true)]
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The OP's code is calling `ToString` on object, so this implementation won't be used 2) It's the `+` operator that's calling `ToString`, and that indirection means the OP's code wouldn't have a warning even if the proper `ToString` implementation would be called.